# undefined_method 'tag_count' using acts_as_taggable_on_steroids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable

I am using `acts_as_taggable` to create a tag cloud for my application. I have a model 'Question' which is using the `acts_as_taggable` plug-in. I basically want to filter the tags for the question model.

I also have a 'Subject' model. So the relation between subjects and questions is that a subject has many questions, and a question belongs to a subject.

So when i call `@subject.questions.tag_counts`, it works fine. But say I call 
`@subject.free_questions.tag_counts`, where `free_questions` is a method I've defined, it gives a me an "undefined_method `tag_counts` for `#<Array>`.  I basically want to find all the tags for a subset of the questions.

Can anybody suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may help to implement `free_questions` as a `named_scope` so you can call association methods on it.

Something like:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :free, :conditions => {:free => true} # conditions that make a question 'free'
end
```

Then you can:

```
@subject.questions.free
```

and I suspect this may work as well. (don't have a lot of experience with `acts_as_taggable`)

```
@subject.questions.free.tag_counts
```

When you use a `named_scope` (instead of a model method you've defined) you get back a proxy object that looks and acts like an `Array`, but allows you to chain `ActiveRecord` association methods onto it.  Any methods that work on `@subject.questions` you should be able to call on `@subject.questions.free`.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! Should have thought of named scopes earlier! Cheers!